# How can I extract specific value from JSON response?

Tags: python, json, gitlab-api

Hi I am trying to get value from JSON response which Im getting from GitLab API. Code should extract "commiter_name" value but it does not work, already tried several options from internet.

```
def getCom():

      com = requests.get("https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/.."
      
      headers = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': '.....'}).content
```

Error:

```
File "getData.py", line 24, in getCom resp = com.json() ["commiter_name"]
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'json'
```

Comment: What's the problem? What is the error message? Please include the details in your question.

Comment: @grandma, You can find more info on the endpoint you are using and sample response here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#list-repository-commits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you did not include you api token in the header. Also please check that the website you are pointing to in the request ends in commits.

Do this,

```
headers = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': 'Your API key here!'}
com = requests.get('https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/5/repository/commits', headers=headers)
print(com.json())
```

You can also try this with the output you got,

```
print(json.loads(com.decode('utf-8')))
```

Your output should be a list of json data. You will be able to access it using a for loop to go through the list and finding your committer_name. For example if it was the first item in the json file.

```
com.json()[0]["commiter_name"]
```

Comment: I am using token just didnt include it to question.

Comment: then show it, but mask the token... we need to see the whole code if you want help.

Comment: @grandma is your token format the same as mine? without the `.content` method

Comment: what output did you get when you tried `print(json.loads(com.decode('utf-8')))`?

Comment: @grandma what was the problem how did you fix it?

Comment: I got JSON file thanks, I'll now try for loop to get trough file.

Comment: I wasnt gettig JSON file in the first place. Now i need to get the commiter_name out of it